# set interval in react repeating itself

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to make a typing animation for my portfolio and I have an array of words i want it to type and i tried to make it so i can just update the word every 5 seconds or so. So i made a set interval that will update a useState that updates the word that will be displayed

```
const [displayTyped, setDisplayTyped] = useState("Developer");
const typedWords = ['Developer', 'Designer', 'Freelancer', 'Photographer'];
let currentWord = 0;

setInterval(() => {
   setDisplayTyped(typedWords[currentWord])

   if(currentWord < 3) {
     currentWord++;
   } else {
     currentWord = 0;
   };     
}, 5000);
```

but when i do that it updates twice and stays at like developer and then the longer i wait it goes through all of them like 6 times and changes it instantly all at once and i don't know who its doing that
and when i `console.log(currentWord)` it shows that it happens two times so I'm thinking that the useState is re-loading the page and its setting the word to the default value

Answer (score 2):

Every time you render, you create a new `setInterval`, and currently have no mechanism of clearing it.  What I would probably do is

```
useEffect(() => {
    let currentWord = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setDisplayTyped(typedWords[currentWord]);
        currentWord = ++currentWord % 4;
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: what does the use effect do i havent learned what that does

Comment: `useEffect` will run the code inside of it once, and then again only when an item in the dependency array is updated.  In this case we pass in an empty `[]`, so it will run the code once.  When the component unmounts, it will run whatever `useEffect` returns, in this case clearing the interval.

Comment: another question i have is how does the `++currentWord % 4` work because i cant think of any way that is would work from what i know

Comment: `4 % 4 === 0`, so `currentWord = ++currentWord % 4` will increment it, but if it's becoming `4`, it will instead become `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const [displayTyped, setDisplayTyped] = useState("Developer");
const typedWords = ['Developer', 'Designer', 'Freelancer', 'Photographer']; // <- move this outside of the component if it's just static.
const [currentWord, setCurrentWord] = useState(0);

useEffect( () => {
    function updateWord() {
        setDisplayTyped(typedWords[currentWord])
        if(currentWord < 3) {
            setCurrentWord(currentWord + 1);
        } else {
            setCurrentWord(0);
        };
    }
    setTimeout(updateWord, 5000);
}, [currentWord])
```

Since React will render this component with every state update, you don't need to use `setInterval`.  The 5 second `setTimeout` call will be called with each render.  `currentWord` will update and so the `useEffect` will run and `setDisplayTyped` will be called.

Here is a sandbox link to show the effect:
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-torvalds-1stwc)